# Plone 4 - customize "related items" screen

Tags: plone

how can I customize the "related items" screen? I want to display the date (effective) and make the list to appear in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Related items is an Archetypes field declared in Products.ATContentTypes package:

https://github.com/plone/Products.ATContentTypes/blob/master/Products/ATContentTypes/content/schemata.py#L38

You could override the template of the widget, in your own content type, or in all existing Plone contents via monkey-patching:

https://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/old/plone_3_theming/buildingblocks/skin/templates/customizing-at-templates/customizing-widgets.html